# What’s the difference between these wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m re-doing some drywall and relocating a couple outlet receptacles. In the kitchen multiple types of wire was used and I’m not sure why. The white 12-2 was used throughout the house, but in the kitchen a silver wrapped wire was used as well. In the first photo the very wide wire on the right runs to an outlet used for a gas range. The smaller silver wire is used randomly for light switches and outlets. Is there a specific application for this wire? It’s in bad shape, so it’s difficult to see any labeling. I’m not sure when this was installed, but the house was built in the 60s.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The “silver wrapped” is the original cloth wrapped wire. Your home looks to have previously been rewired. This is quite common for houses built as late as the 50’s to have this original cloth wrapped wire. The 60’s may be some cloth was still out there but if it is in bad shape why not replace it there is nothing special about it.

Comment: Thanks. I will go ahead an replace the wire. In some areas it is n really bad shape and almost looks burnt.

Comment: That old cloth may be ok it’s hard to tell from the outer covering, where I usually notice problems is the insulation around the wires it gets brittle , sometimes I use shrink tubing for repairs, with the walls open it would be best to replace if just for ease of being able to go to sleep not worrying because you got it fixed up like new.